# Show that $\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 (\sin^2 x)^{1/3}} dx$ is finite.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Show that $\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^2 (\sin^2 x)^{1/3}} dx$ is finite. I've been trying to use Holder inequality but it seems I can't get the right combination of $p$ and $q$. Maybe I'm on the wrong track?

Comment: Improper integral with lots of (periodic) singularities at zeros of $\sin x$, summable though... $1/x^2$ kills the rest. Maybe best is to split the integral into a series between poles.

Comment: The integral from $n\pi$ to $(n+1)\pi$ of $(\sin^2 x)^{-1/3}$ seems to be controllable.

Comment: You may notice that the singularities at $x=n\pi$ are integrable.

Comment: Ok. I will try to break it into a infinite series.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Hi, how would you control the integral you mentioned. I'm trying but fail to control it. Thanks.

Comment: I will be vague. Look at the integral from $o$ to $\pi/2$. At $x\ne 0$, the function $\sin x$ is bigger than say $x/10$ (my constant $10$ is much too large, but it will do the job). So $(\sin^2 x)^{1/3}\gt x^{2/3}/10^{2/3}$, and therefore  its reciprocal is less rhan a constant times $x^{-2/3}$. This function has a finite integral over $(0,\pi/2)$. Shift by $n\pi$. The integral does not change.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think the inequality part is the part that I don't know. Why is $sinx > x/10$?

Comment: Remember, we are talking about the interval $(0,\pi/2]$, nothing else. Near $0$ we have $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is nearly $1$, way bigger than $1/10$. And as $x$ increases towards $\pi$, $\sin x/x$ decreases some, but not very much. One could give a formal proof, just a bit of calculus. Or to be persuaded, graph $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ over the interval. Actually, one only needs the lower bound near $0$, say to $0.1$ radians, and one can get that from the series, and in other ways.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you! I understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{\left(\sin^2 x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \left|\int_{\pi}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2\left(\sin^2 x\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}\,dx\right|&\leq& \pi\left(\frac{1}{\pi^2}+\frac{1}{4\pi^2}+\frac{1}{9\pi^2}\ldots\right)\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}\\&=&\frac{\pi}{6}\cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

The exact value of the integral is given by:
$$ I = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\psi'(1+x)\,dx}{\left(\sin^2 (\pi x)\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
and by computing the Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{(\sin^2 x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$, the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{(x+\pi)^2}$ and keeping just the terms $A e^{-\pi s},B s^2 e^{-\pi s}$ of their product we get:
$$ I\leq \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)}{4\pi^{7/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}\left(5\pi^2-\psi'\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)+\psi'\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)\leq\color{red}{\frac{4}{5}}.$$